# Perfoemance Tuning in postgis GeoLocation Using Special Indexing

Tags: indexing, postgis, database-performance, postgresql-9.6

I want to tune performance of fetching geometric areas (inside a polygon). How and which indexing will be favorable to optimize search.

Using Extension :  PostGIS

Comment: Have you tried `GIST`?

Comment: `CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table USING GIST (the_geom);`

Comment: You can use st_boundary(the_geom) like a "secondary" index for  your geometris. And in queries use this plus gist index over the_geom

select boundary && the_geom  AND <other geom functions>.